VBA For Each Loop Crashes Excel
I have a loop which reliably crashes Excel when it is run at full speed. If it is stepped through in the debugger, there is no problem with the loop, and it produces the correct output.
Private Function ff_table() As String
    Dim flt As CFlight
    Dim s As String
    Dim acft As String
    
    On Error GoTo ff_tableErr
    For Each flt In Me
        If Not InStr(acft, flt.TailNum) > 0 Then
            acft = acft & ";" & flt.TailNum
            s = s & flt.ff_table_line & vbCrLf
        End If
    Next flt
    ff_table = s
    
ff_tableExit:
    Exit Function
    
ff_tableErr:
    HandleError "CFlights.ff_table()"
    Resume ff_tableExit
End Function

The calling object is a custom object, the relevant code for which I've included below.
Friend Function ff_table_line() As String
    Dim s As String
    On Error GoTo ff_table_lineErr
    
    s = Me.TailNum & "," & Me.Aircraft.Model & "," & Me.Aircraft.ACType & ",,,," & Me.Aircraft.AppsCategory
    s = s & "," & Me.Aircraft.AppsClass & ",," & Me.Aircraft.Power & ",,,,"
    s = s & ",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"
    ff_table_line = s                       'return value
    
ff_table_lineExit:
    Exit Function
    
ff_table_lineErr:
    HandleError "CFlight.ff_table_line()"
    Resume ff_table_lineExit
End Function

This routine creates one line of a CSV file, pulling various properties from the object and storing them in a string. It is a quite simple routine, and it works fine when running through it slowly but causes all of Excel to crash when running full speed. The crash takes the form of all Excel windows closing without warning. The exception handling that is in the code does not get enacted.
I have done quite a few google searches to no avail. This may be an iteration problem within Excel.
Here is the code for the iterable:
Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
Attribute NewEnum.VB_UserMemId = -4
Attribute NewEnum.VB_MemberFlags = "40"
    Set NewEnum = colFlights.[_NewEnum]
End Property

Any help that you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Try adding a DoEvents to the loop first. There are some race conditions in Excel when using VBA. The ones I am most familiar involve it trying to plot lines and points before the axis scaling has been entirely processed. A judicious short wait here and there can fix those. Also add a simple Debug.Print to the start of the error handlers for testing.

The error handlers already have a debug.Print included in the code, but the DoEvents is certainly worth a shot.

What I have done that seems to fix the problem is in the For Each loop, in this loop I have removed the references to the custom object and instead only referred to the internal Collection Object, thus the code looks like this:
    For Each flt In colFlights

Instead of using the Me construct in vba, this allows vba to use a built-in type to iterate over and it does not cause any memory leaking or crashes.
Me refers to the specific instance of the Class so it 'should' be acceptable to use, but this is not the first time that I have had difficulty using this construct, but this is the first time that I have tried this workaround and I have been pleasantly surprised.
If anyone out there knows the 'why' of this, post the answer and I will assess yours as the answer.
